# Understanding Private Variables (Closure?) in Javascript with specific example

Tags: javascript

OK, I have tried to use a closure to no avail on the following code to keep a variable private. I am brand new to javascript and have read a number of posts about closures and can still not wrap my head around them. Below, I have a function that, upon each press of a particular button, displays the next word in an array. I want my counter variable ("whatNumber" below) that I am using in this function to not be global but I cannot figure out how. Here is my simple code:

```
var wordList = ["jumper", "stumpy", "smelly gumdrops", "awesome puttputt", "soilent green"];
var whatNumber = 0;

function changeWord(){
    if (whatNumber < wordList.length) {
        alert(wordList[whatNumber]);
        whatNumber++;
    }
};
```

Comment: Wrap the `changeWord` routine in an IIFE (`(function() { ... })()`) and declare your variable inside that. Return the function from inside the IIFE.

Comment: IIFE = Imediate Inkoked Function Expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function changeWord(){
    var wordList = ["jumper", "stumpy", "smelly gumdrops", "awesome puttputt", "soilent green"];
    var whatNumber = 0;
    return function alertWord(){
        if (whatNumber < wordList.length) {
            alert(wordList[whatNumber]);
            whatNumber++;
        }
    }
};
//to run this
var alertNewWord = changeWord();
alertNewWord() //jumper
alertNewWord() //stumpy
```

This comes with a bonus of being able to have different functions having different levels of alerting. e.g: if you do another `var anotherAlertFn = changeWord()` and you call `anotherAlertFn()` it will result in `"jumper"`. The initial functions (i.e: `alertNewWord()`) will still have it's own state, i.e: `whatNumber === 3` while `anotherAlertFn` has `whatNumber === 1`. This can be very useful, imagine a function keeping score for different players in a game. Every player can use the same function without being able to cheat (i.e: change their score) and never affecting other players' scores.

Comment: OK that works perfectly! I am going to study this. Since I know exactly what it does I should be able to start to figure out closures. Thanks so much!

Comment: @silent_john check my edit with further explanation on closures.

Comment: Wow, this is great. To help motivate me to learn javascript, my first project is actually a word game like catchphrase! So your hypothetical example of points will be perfect too. Thanks again!

Comment: @silent_john checkout a small ["Guess the Number" game](https://github.com/kdamball/guessGame/blob/master/guess.js) I made a while back. It uses the same concept.